# performing a join operation and filter records according to the MAX value of a partucular column

Tags: sql, oracle, join, groupwise-maximum

I need some assistance with the following scenario,

I have two tables,

```
MESSAGE_CONTEXT_TABLE (CONTEXT_ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,PACKAGE) PK(CONTEXT_ID,PACKAGE)
PACKAGE_INFO_TABLE (PACKAGE,DESCRIPTION,PACKAGE_ORDER) PK (PACKAGE_NAME)
```

I need to perform a join on these tables. When there are multiple records with the same CONTEXT_ID (but with different PACKAGE) I need to take the row which corresponds to the maximum PACKAGE_ORDER in PACKAGE_INFO_TABLE.

Could somebody suggest me a way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MESSAGE_CONTEXT_TABLE tm
     INNER JOIN PACKAGE_INFO_TABLE tp ON tm.package = tp.package
WHERE tp.package_order >= ALL (SELECT tp1.PACKAGE_ORDER
                               FROM MESSAGE_CONTEXT_TABLE tm1
                                    INNER JOIN PACKAGE_INFO_TABLE tp1 ON tm1.package = tp1.package
                               WHERE tm1.context_id = tm.context_id)
```

---

Or this way:

```
SELECT tm.*, tp.*
FROM MESSAGE_CONTEXT_TABLE tm
     INNER JOIN PACKAGE_INFO_TABLE tp ON tm.package = tp.package
     LEFT JOIN PACKAGE_INFO_TABLE tp1 ON tm.package = tp1.package
                                         AND tp1.package_order > tp.package_order
WHERE tp1.package_order IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  mct.Context_ID, MAX(pit.Package_Order)
FROM Package_Info_Table pit
INNER JOIN MESSAGE_CONTEXT_TABLE mct
ON mct.Context_ID = pit.Context_ID
AND mct.Package <> pit.package
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses two CTE. The first (`allorders`) joins both tables, without worrying with `PACKAGE_ORDER`. The second (`maxorders`) get the max package order for each context id using the previous result. The main query returns the rows of `allorders` whose `CONTEXT_ID` and `PACKAGE_ORDER` exist in `maxorders`:

```
WITH allorders AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM MESSAGE_CONTEXT_TABLE msg
  JOIN PACKAGE_INFO_TABLE    pkg ON (pkg.PACKAGE = msg.PACKAGE)
)
, maxorders AS (
  SELECT aux.CONTEXT_ID, MAX(aux.PACKAGE_ORDER) AS max_PACKAGE_ORDER
  FROM allorders aux
  GROUP BY aux.CONTEXT_ID
)
SELECT *
FROM allorders aor
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 'x'
  FROM maxorders mor
  WHERE aor.CONTEXT_ID    = mor.CONTEXT_ID
    AND aor.PACKAGE_ORDER = mor.max_PACKAGE_ORDER
);
```

I created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0b9bc/12) for this query.

Comment: Is this the structure of the query? I can't run it ( though tried with different changes)

Comment: Hi, @pragan, I'm sorry, I haven't check the syntax before. I created a fiddle for it so you can add some data and see if the results are the expected.

Comment: thnx. But still I can't get the result I want with the query. 

sample data,

MESSAGE_CONTEXT_TABLE

`CONTEXT_ID    NAME DESCRIPTION PACKAGE
    1      Context_1 Context_1 pkg_1
    2      Context_1 Context_1 pkg_2
    3      Context_3 Context_3 pkg_1
`
PACKAGE_INFO_TABLE

`PACKAGE  DESCRIPTION  PACKAGE_ORDER
  pkg_1    Package 1 1
  pkg_2    Package 2 2
`
Sample result set,

`CONTEXT_ID     NAME  PACKAGE  PACKAGE_ORDER
     1     Context_1   pkg_1   1
     2     Context_2   pkg_2      2
     3     Context_3   pkg_1      1 
`
If we take the first 2 rows, I only need the 2nd one from those 2